# Create Flash Cards Dynamically in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible, with the following Fiddle, to allow a user to create flash cards dynamically by inputting data into an `<input>` field?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/InnovativeDave/cu436vem/)

If it's possible, it would be very much appreciated if a new fiddle could be provided, as I am new to coding.

Thank You!

```js
$(function(){
  var maxCards = $('.card').length;
  // turn card
  for (var i = 1; i <= maxCards; ++i) {
    $('._' + i).click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('flipped');
      $(this).find('.front').addClass('showingBack');
      $(this).find('.front').css("z-index", 0);
      $(this).css("z-index", i);
    });
  }
  // reset stack
  $('#reset button').click(function(){
    $('.card').removeClass('flipped');
    $('.card').find('.front').removeClass('showingBack');
    $('.card').find('.front').css("z-index", 2);
    for (var j = 0; j < maxCards; ++j) {
      $('.card:eq(' + j + ')').css("z-index", maxCards - j);
    }
  });
});




$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input placeholder="Question" type="text" name="mytext[]"/><input placeholder="Answer"  type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  font-family: Indie Flower, sans-serif;
}

#reset {
  text-align: center;
}
#reset button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin: auto;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
}
#reset button:active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#stack {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
.card .front {
  background: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.card .front p {
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.card .back {
  background: white linear-gradient(transparent, transparent 20%, hotpink 20%, hotpink 21%, transparent 21%, transparent 31%, lightblue 31%, lightblue 32%, transparent 32%, transparent 42%, lightblue 42%, lightblue 43%, transparent 43%, transparent 53%, lightblue 53%, lightblue 54%, transparent 54%, transparent 64%, lightblue 64%, lightblue 65%, transparent 65%, transparent 75%, lightblue 75%, lightblue 76%, transparent 76%, transparent 86%, lightblue 86%, lightblue 87%, transparent 87%, transparent 97%);
  font-size: 11pt;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
.card .back p {
  margin: 40px 5px 5px 5px;
}

._1 {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

._2 {
  top: 3px;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
}

._3 {
  top: 6px;
  right: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
}

._4 {
  top: 9px;
  right: 6px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateX(30px);
  animation: flip 1s;
}

.showingBack {
  animation: showBack 1s;
}

@keyframes flip {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateX(30px);
  }
}
@keyframes showBack {
  0% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  25% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  50% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
Import FlashCard Text Below:
</h2>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Flash Cards</button>
    <button>
    Create Flash Cards
    </button>
    <div><input placeholder="Question" type="text" name="mytext[]"><input placeholder="Answer" type="text" name="mytext[]"/></div>
</div>
<hr>

<p id='reset'>
  <button align="center">Reset stack</button>
</p>
<div id='stack'>
  <div class='card _1'>
    <div class='front'>
      <p>What is 1+3?</p>
    </div>
    <div class='back'>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='card _2'>
    <div class='front'>
      <p>What is 2-1?</p>
    </div>
    <div class='back'>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='card _3'>
    <div class='front'>
      <p>What is Pi?</p>
    </div>
    <div class='back'>
      <p>3.14...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='card _4'>
    <div class='front'>
      <p>What is 1/2?</p>
    </div>
    <div class='back'>
      <p>0.5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a totally different way to create flash cards.](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/electronic-3x5-cards/)

Flash card content goes into google drive sheets.  Easy to use, easy to update.  Then use Google's API to download the data in JSON format.

The code is as simple as putting this code in the body of your html file.

```
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/XXXXXXXX/od6/public/full?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=useJSONdata"></script>
```

In the script portion of your site you would have:

```
function useJSONdata(root) { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(root, null, 4));
    // Understanding the object root is a great way to understand what is going on with JSON
    var entries = root.feed.entry || [];  .. etc.
```

Analyse the data you need, run a for loop, create a string of content to be pasted back into the Document Object Model / HTML / body.

Finally use jQuery mobile tools to create a mobile ready application.   I used both their js and css files. Very nice. I made use of three mobile events “swipeleft” “swiperight” and “taphold”. Swipe left to go to next slide. Swipe right to go to previous slide. Long touch and hold to reveal answer to question.

I realize this wasn't exactly what you were asking for, and although an active input is nice, I'm thinking a spreadsheet format for a series of flash cards with data persistence (and the ability to do edits) is a pretty good way to go.